# How to show clocks on pin/pattern lockscreen (Cyanogenmod 12 / Android 5)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, clock, xposed-framework

I have configured my CM12 to show pattern on screen wake-up, and unfortunately there are no clocks! Clocks are shown on the first screen when you need to pull the bottom up to open pinpad or pattern dots. How to show clocks above pinpad or pattern? There is more than enough space and i can find screenshots from Android 4.x where clocks present.

I have root and Xposed framework, so any solution would help. Thanks!

Comment: Disable to show pattern on screen wake up.

Comment: This is the thing i *enabled* so why disable it? It won't help to get clocks above pattern anyway.

Comment: The time doesn't show up in the status bar? It usually does when the lock screen clock is hidden.

Comment: I'm on Nexus's stock ROM, and I also observed this behaviour since Android 5.0, and until the latest Android 6.0.1. I believe it's due to replacement of lockscreen widget with lockscreen notification. Previously, [the clock is considered as lockscreen widget, and the pattern lock will be shown just below it](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/10/31/apk-download-android-4-4-clockalarmtimerstopwatch-app-with-fixed-font-four-tabs-new-time-picker-and-more/).

Comment: @Dhruvil Mehta: status bar is not what i need. I is too small.

Comment: @Andrew T.: Thank you! You clarified everything. This is the real answer :)

Comment: I do not even see the status bar :( Is there a way to show it on pattern lock screen?

Comment: Is there also a solution? I read the answer of @andrew-t like "It's not possible" but the bug is fixed in 6.0.1